# Python: How to import, from two modules, Classes that have same names?

Tags: python, class, import

I'm writing a python programm to do granular syncs between different DB.

I'm using SQLAlchemy and a module named sqlautocode for DB inspecting and Schema Classes production.

Having two DB to sync, with same tables name, the Classes written by sqlautocode results with same names.

I have to import theese Classes with arbitrary prefixes, I'm thinking about something like this:

```
from module_name import * with prefixes
```

Otherwise I should import every Classes name with an "as" modifier, like this:

```
from module_name import x as master_x
```

First of HardCode name extraction procedures with control lists and exec/eval complex code I'd like some suggestions about it.

UPDATE:
The solution is a sqlautocode option: --table-prefix=TABLE_PREFIX

thank you all

Comment: Why not just do `import module_name, module2_name` ?

Answer (score 8):

Just import the modules and don't try to pull the names from them. `from X import Y` should be used sporadically, anyway.

```
import module_a
import module_b

module_a.x
module_b.x
```

Comment: I need to pull the names from them, the answer is whitin sqlautoconde command help:

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to import classes from modules in this case. Instead import both modules. Like this:

```
import moda, modb

moda.MyClass()
modb.MyClass()
```

On the other hand this doesn't let you use cool tools like `pyflakes`. So I would do the hard work (you have to do it only once, right?) and import classes with renaming. I am great supporter of `from x import something` because it let's you detect errors the earliest possible.

Comment: I need to pull the names from them. I found the answer inside the sqlautocode help: --table-prefix=TABLE_PREFIX